# How to make a single row of data editable under a section based on the status of the record while other rows on the same section non editable?

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere, ibm-maximo-worker-insights

The requirement is as follows:
In the application Company I have added a custom tab called revisionlog and this revisionlog captures any revision to vendor records.
This revisionlog records can be added and modified only by certain users belonging to a security group, however the new requirement is to allow only one row of data in this revisionlog section editable if the vendor record has a particular status, all other rows will be non editable.
Any ideas, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What are your criteria to determine which row is editable?

Let's say only the last revisionlog is editable.

- Add a persistent flag attribute to your revisionlog object
- With an object launch point automation script, on the before save event, set this flag to true. Set the other occurrence to false by getting it's mbo instance from a custom relationship, something like that: `company=:company and flag=1`.
- Use a standard signature option based on this flag (and company's current status?) to manage the editability of each record. This might be helpful: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLW8/com.ibm.mbs.doc/condexpmgr/c_expression_syntax_cond_expressions_classes.html